# What is the design philosophy behind Promise.reject(reason) wrapping the reason with a Promise while Promise.resolve() not doing so?

Tags: javascript, promise

So I was reading the article on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) about Promises and got stuck here:

> Unlike Promise.resolve(), Promise.reject() always wraps reason in a new Promise object, even when reason is already a Promise.

I'm just trying to understand what difference it makes in coding. What would happen if `Reject` doesn't wrap the `reason` with another Promise just as `resolve` does and how exactly this simplifies the usage.

Appreciate some hypothetical examples.

Comment: It's not `Promise.reject` that is the odd one out, it's `Promise.resolve` that does "unwrap" promises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't speak to the design philosophy except for those who designed the A+ spec. But as to the actual examples...

Promises automatically flatten on the happy path: `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(5));` is just a Promise of 5, not a Promise of a Promise of 5.

But `Promise.reject` does *not* automatically flatten, `Promise.reject(Promise.resolve(5))` actually *is* a (rejected) Promise of a Promise of 5:

```
Promise.reject(Promise.resolve(5))
  .catch(p => console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(p)))
```

will log `[object Promise]`.

Side Note: the decision for Promises to have that auto-flattening behavior on the happy path was [controversial at the time of the proposal back in 2013](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/94), many people felt and still feel that Promises should not do that for various reasons, you can read the linked Github discussion for details. If you want to see what a non-automatically-flattening Futures API looks like, [check this out](https://github.com/folktale/data.task).

> What would happen if Reject doesn't wrap the reason with another Promise just as resolve does

the Promise would autoflatten and you'd just get the rejection value of 5 instead of Promise of 5.

This may be a neat piece of trivia, but there is a strong convention in the JS community to not reject Promises with non-Errors (like other Promises). I seem to recall some controversy over React.js rejecting Promises with non-Errors but I'm having a little trouble tracking down the reference.

At any rate, a lot of `.catch` code (or code in the `catch` block of an async try/catch) implicitly assumes the caught value is an error and will do things like try to destructure a `message` property *which will throw at runtime* (which is why Typescript will not let you do that without a cast or runtime check) so please consider **very** carefully before you decide you need to reject with something that isn't an instance of Error.

Comment: Perfect. The explanation is neat and clear.

Comment: "*React.js rejecting Promises with non-Errors*" - do they? Maybe you refer to Suspense, which afaik was implemented by *throwing* promise values?

Comment: @Bergi you're probably right, I may have misremembered that.

Answer (score 2):

`Promise.resolve` (and its related behavior in `new Promise`, `then` return values, and `async`) ensures that Promises don't become nested: you're indicating that the value to return or resolve isn't ready yet and might actually wind up as a rejected promise. `Promise.reject` can be simpler, as it is an asynchronous analog of `throw` and can therefore treat its results opaquely.

This matches the original proposal in [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/), where both 2.2.7 and 2.3.3.3 specify the that the promise resolution process runs on the `resolve` case but not the `reject` case.

Furthermore, it is unclear what to do when `throw`ing a Promise that resolves: Is the resolved value the reason that should be passed along? Or does successful return of the function mean that the path should switch back to the `resolve` path in further chaining, thereby making `reject(promiseValue)` equivalent to `resolve(promiseValue)`? Error cases analogous to `throw` will almost certainly have a `reason` value synchronously, so there's no reason to `throw` a Promise, and in handlers if you need asynchronous error details you can `return` a Promise that you know will eventually `reject`.